# How do I get gnome-do to run terminal/bash commands?

Tags: gnome-do

I just started using gnome-do (awesome little application!) in the past few weeks, but am having one problem with it. I can't figure out how to get it to run terminal commands without opening the terminal, the same way that the "run application" dialogue can. For example, if I type `pkill misbehavingapplicationX` into gnome-do, it won't do anything. And typing run first doesn't do anything either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [GNOME Terminal plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20120516185056/http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/GNOMETerminal_Plugin).

Follow the link for a description of how to use it.

Comment: That link seems to no longer be up. Any idea of where we might go instead?